# Why doesn't Mac OS X source ~/.bashrc?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, command-line

I found a lot of people figuring out why instruction similar to this :

> ```
> Put X to your ~/.bashrc and you can do Y
> ```

don't work.

It always turns out that Mac OS X's bash's startup files (or Mac's Bash itself) doesn't source ~/.bashrc file, either in the login shell, or in a shell spawned from window system - like Terminal app in Mac OS X)

Why is this, when all other Unix-like systems with Bash I've worked with before have done this?

PS:

I found what Bash itself says about startup files (which could be helpful) :

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
>   and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
>   the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may
>   be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

Source : http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: I also noticed that `~/.bash_profile` is executed but not `~/.bashrc`. Wierd.

Answer (score 95):

In OSX the terminal  by default starts a login session so reads .bash_profile etc. (The GUI login process that asks for your name and password does not use shell scripts and starts no shell it is all done from launchd and the workspace)

On other Unices xterm runs a non login shell by default so they read .bashrc as the scripts that present you with your password etc at login call the login session and all terminals are sub process of this and inherit the shell environment.

From the GNU document you referred to

> Invoked as an interactive non-login shell
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash
> reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This
> may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option
> will force Bash to read and execute commands from file instead of
> ~/.bashrc.
>
> So, typically, your ~/.bash_profile contains the line
>
> ```
> if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
> ```
>
> after (or before) any
> login-specific initializations.

Comment: This may have been true at one time, but it's not any longer. First, Apple has changed  the default shell from `bash` to `zsh`.  Second, Apple has put in place two *"system-wide"* `*rc` files to configure `bash`: `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` and `/etc/bashrc`. That they have done all of this with virtually zero documentation is... *par for the course*.

Comment: This is still true. Terminal.app starts a login session (so reads zlogin or zprofile) Whilst xterm etc doesn't as the login shell is earlier in the boot phase - systemd migh have chnaged that

Comment: No, it's not true any longer - sorry.

Answer (score 19):

`bash` only reads `.bashrc` for *non-login* shells:

> When  an  interactive  shell  that  is  not  a  login  shell  is started, bash reads and executes commands from
>          ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.  This may be inhibited by using the --norc option.  The  --rcfile  file  option
>          will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.

As Terminal starts `bash` as a login shell (run `w` to see that the `bash` instances are executed as `-bash`), `.bashrc` is never read automatically.

Comment: So the point is, that Termina app on Mac OS X always create "login" instance of bash ? Why ?  If you really don't login. (You have login earlier from GUI)

Comment: Well it is the first time you run the shell as you so it is a login, in X11 based Unices you start by running the shell which then runs X so it is not a login