# What are the practical differences between Bash and Zsh?

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh, catalina

With the news that [Catalina will default to Zsh instead of Bash](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT208050), I'm finding lots of results telling me about the switch, and that it may cause problems with shell scripts, but I'm not familiar enough with Zsh to know what those problems might be.

My shell scripts are really not that complicated, but I've only ever used Bash on macOS and Linux - zero experience with Zsh. Can anyone provide a simple practical comparison, or specific stumbling blocks I will need to know, so that I can start working towards being ready for the new shell when Catalina is released?

Comment: All this hubbub that you have been reading is much to do about nothing. The OS assigns a "default" shell when creating new users, no reason more . Bash isn't going away, and you can use that as your shell or any of the other shells currently offered.

Comment: Speaking as someone who's used both and landed on bash -- the only thing that made me really, deeply unhappy with zsh was its decision to break POSIX compliance when the standard canonicalizes admittedly-bad design decisions in ways that made it easy to get sloppy about correctness when trying to write scripts that needed to be compatible with other, strictly-POSIX-superset shells. Unfortunately, that "only thing" can be a pretty big one. Still, ksh93 isn't going away, and anyone serious about bash wouldn't use the ancient 3.x release Apple ships anyhow.

Comment: As a follow-up - installed Catalina yesterday, switched to zsh, imported bash_history and copied over some of my preferred aliases from bash_profile, nothing seems to have broken. Appreciate all of the information provided by everyone here and hopefully it helps others out as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good comment. WRT being "serious", and using `bash version 3.2.57(1)`: Do you know if Apple uses `bash` for anything "important" on the system?

Comment: If you use [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org) to run any X11 applications but have trouble running them under zsh, you might want to check this Apple discussion about [running them under bash instead](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253467080).

Answer (score 416, accepted):

First, some important things:

1. **Bash isn't going away**. If you're already using bash, nothing will change for you. All that changes is that zsh will be the default login shell for *new* accounts, and even then, you can select bash instead.
2. **Scripts are not affected**. What changes is the shell for interactive use, i.e. the shell in terminals (and also a few other things that use the login shell, such as crontabs). If you have a script in a file with execution permissions, starting with a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) such as `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, it'll keep working exactly as before.
3. Zsh's syntax is not completely compatible with bash, but it's close. A lot of code will keep working, for example typical aliases and functions. The main differences are in interactive configuration features.

Now, assuming you're considering switching to zsh, which has been a possibility for years, here are the main differences you'll encounter. This is not an exhaustive list!

#### Main differences for interactive use

**Configuration files**: [bash reads](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) (mainly) `.bashrc` in non-login interactive shells (but macOS starts a login shell in terminals by default), `.profile` or `.bash_profile` in login shells, and `.inputrc`. [Zsh reads](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html) (mainly) `.zshrc` (in all interactive shells) and `.zprofile` (in login shells). This means that none of your bash customizations will apply: you'll need to port them over. You can't just copy the files because many things will need tweaking.

**Key bindings** use completely different syntax. Bash uses [`.inputrc` and the `bind` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html) to bind keys to [readline commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bindable-Readline-Commands.html). Zsh uses [the `bindkey` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-bindkey) to bind keys to [zle widgets](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets). Most readline commands have a zsh equivalent, but it isn't always a perfect equivalence.

Speaking of key bindings, if you use Vi(m) as your in-terminal editor but not as your command line mode in the shell, you'll notice zsh defaults to vi editing mode (i.e. with command and insert modes) if `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` is set to `vi` or `vim`. `bindkey -e` switches to emacs mode (i.e. where you can always type directly).

**Prompt**: bash sets the prompt (mainly) from [`PS1`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#index-PS1) which contains [backslash escapes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html#Controlling-the-Prompt). Zsh sets the prompt mainly from [`PS1`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-PS1) which contains [percent escapes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion). Although the concepts are similar, the escape codes are completely different. The functionality of bash's [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND) is available in zsh via the [`precmd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-precmd) and [`preexec`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-preexec) [hook functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions). Zsh has more convenience mechanisms to build fancy prompts including a [prompt theme mechanism](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Prompt-Themes).

The basic **command line history** mechanisms (navigation with <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>, search with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, history expansion with `!!` and friends, last argument recall with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or `$_`) work in the same way, but there are a lot of differences in the details, too many to list here. You can copy your `.bash_history` to `.zsh_history` if you haven't changed a shell option that changes the file format.

**Completion**: both shells default to a basic completion mode that mostly completes command and file names, and switch to a fancy mode by including `bash_completion` on bash or by running `compinit` in zsh. You'll find some commands that bash handles better and some that zsh handles better. Zsh is usually more precise, but sometimes gives up where bash does something that isn't correct but is sensible. To specify possible completions for a command, zsh has three mechanisms:

- The [“old” completion mechanism with `compctl`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Using-compctl.html#Completion-Using-compctl) which you can forget about.
- The [“new” completion mechanism with `compadd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System) and [lots of functions that begin with underscore](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Widgets) and a [powerful but complex user configuration mechanism](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Widgets).
- An [emulation to support bash completion functions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-bashcompinit) which you can enable by running `bashcompinit`. The emulation isn't 100% perfect but it usually works.

Many of bash's [**`shopt`** settings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) have a corresponding [`setopt`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Options) in zsh.

Zsh doesn't treat **`#`** as a comment start on the command line by default, only in scripts (including `.zshrc` and such). To enable interactive comments, run [`setopt interactive_comments`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-INTERACTIVE_005fCOMMENTS).

#### Main differences for scripting

(and for power users on the command line of course)

In bash, `$foo` takes the value of `foo`, splits it at whitespace characters, and for each whitespace-separated part, if it contains wildcard characters and matches an existing file, replaces the pattern by the list of matches. To just get the value of `foo`, you need `"$foo"`. The same applies to command substitution `$(foo)`. In zsh, **`$foo`** is the value of `foo` and **`$(foo)`** is the output of `foo` minus its final newlines, with two exceptions. If a word becomes empty due to expanding empty unquoted variables, it's removed (e.g. `a=; b=; printf "%s\n" one "$a$b" three $a$b five` prints `one`, an empty line, `three`, `five`). The result of an unquoted command substitution is split at whitespace but the pieces don't undergo wildcard matching.

Bash **arrays** are indexed from 0 to (length-1). Zsh arrays are indexed from 1 to length. You can make 0-indexing the default with [`setopt ksh_arrays`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-KSH_005fARRAYS). Zsh requires fewer braces (unless `ksh_arrays` is enabled). For example, suppose `a=(first second third "" last)`.

| Functionality | Bash syntax | Idiomatic zsh syntax | Expansion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First element | `${a[0]}` | `$a[1]` | `first` |
| Second element | `${a[1]}` | `$a[2]` | `second` |
| Last element | `${a[${#a[@]}-1]}` | `$a[-1]` | `last` |
| Length | `${#a[@]}` | `$#a` | `5` |
| All the elements | `"${a[@]}"` | `"${a[@]}"` or `"${(@)a}"` | `first` `second` `third` (empty word) `last` |
| All the non-empty elements |  | `$a` | `first` `second` `third` `last` |

Bash has extra **[wildcard patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)** such as `@(foo|bar)` to match `foo` or `bar`, which are only enabled with `shopt -s extglob`. In zsh, you can enable [these patterns](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#ksh_002dlike-Glob-Operators) with `setopt ksh_glob`, but there's also a simpler-to-type [native syntax](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) such as `(foo|bar)`, some of which requires `setopt extended_glob` (do put that in your `.zshrc`, and it's on by default in completion functions). Zsh has `**/` for recursive directory traversal (as does modern bash but not the bash 3.2 that ships with macOS).

In bash, by default, if a **wildcard pattern doesn't match** any file, it's left unchanged. In zsh, by default, you'll get an error, which is usually the safest setting. If you want to pass a wildcard parameter to a command, use quotes. You can switch to the bash behavior with [`setopt no_nomatch`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NOMATCH). You can make non-matching wildcard patterns expand to an empty list instead with [`setopt null_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NULL_005fGLOB).

In bash, the **right-hand side of a pipeline** runs in a subshell. In zsh, it runs in the parent shell, so you can write things like `somecommand | read output`.

#### Some nice zsh features

Here are a few nice zsh features that bash doesn't have (at least not without some serious elbow grease). Once again, this is just a selection of the ones I consider the most useful.

**[Glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers)** allow matching files based on metadata such as their time stamp, their size, etc. They also allow tweaking the output. The syntax is rather cryptic, but it's extremely convenient. Here are a few examples:

- `foo*(.)`: only regular files matching `foo*` and symbolic links to regular files, not directories and other special files.
- `foo*(*.)`: only executable regular files matching `foo*`.
- `foo*(-.)`: only regular files matching `foo*`, not symbolic links and other special files.
- `foo*(-@)`: only dangling symbolic links matching `foo*`.
- `foo*(om)`: the files matching `foo*`, sorted by last modification date, most recent first. Note that if you pass this to `ls`, it'll do its own sorting. This is especially useful in…
- `foo*(om[1,10])`: the 10 most recent files matching `foo*`, most recent first.
- `foo*(Lm+1)`: files matching `foo*` whose size is at least 1MB.
- `foo*(N)`: same as `foo*`, but if this doesn't match any file, produce an empty list regardless of the setting of the `null_glob` option (see above).
- `*(D)`: match all files including dot files (except `.` and `..`).
- `foo/bar/*(:t)` (using a [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers)): the files in `foo/bar`, but with only the base name of the file. E.g. if there is a `foo/bar/qux.txt`, it's expanded as `qux.txt`.
- `foo/bar/*(.:r)`: take regular files under `foo/bar` and remove the extension. E.g. `foo/bar/qux.txt` is expanded as `foo/bar/qux`.
- `foo*.odt(e\''REPLY=$REPLY:r.pdf'\')`: take the list of files matching `foo*.odt`, and replace `.odt` by `.pdf` (regardless of whether the PDF file exists).

Here are a few useful zsh-specific **[wildcard patterns](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators)**.

- `foo*.txt~foobar*`: all `.txt` files whose name starts with `foo` but not `foobar`.
- `image<->.jpg(n)`: all `.jpg` files whose base name is `image` followed by a number, e.g. `image3.jpg` and `image22.jpg` but not `image-backup.jpg`. The glob qualifier `(n)` causes the files to be listed in numerical order, i.e. `image9.jpg` comes before `image10.jpg` (you can make this the default even without `-n` with [`setopt numeric_glob_sort`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NUMERIC_005fGLOB_005fSORT)).

To **mass-rename files**, zsh provides a very convenient tool: the [`zmv` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv). Suggested for your `.zshrc`:

```
autoload zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C' zln='zmv -L'
```

Example:

```
zmv '(*).jpeg' '$1.jpg'
zmv '(*)-backup.(*)' 'backups/$1.$2'
```

Bash has a few [ways to apply transformations when taking the value of a variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). Zsh has [some of the same and many more](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion).

Zsh has a number of little convenient features to **change directories**. Turn on [`setopt auto_cd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTO_005fCD) to change to a directory when you type its name without having to type `cd` (bash also has this nowadays). You can use the [two-argument form to `cd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-cd) to change to a directory whose name is close to the current directory. For example, if you're in `/some/where/foo-old/deeply/nested/inside` and you want to go to `/some/where/foo-new/deeply/nested/inside`, just type `cd old new`.

To assign a value to a variable, you of course write `VARIABLE=VALUE`. To **edit the value of a variable** interactively, just run [`vared VARIABLE`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vared).

#### Final advice

Zsh comes with a configuration interface that supports a few of the most common settings, including canned recipes for things like case-insensitive completion. To (re)run this interface (the first line is not needed if you're using a configuration file that was edited by `zsh-newuser-install`):

```
autoload -U zsh-newuser-install
zsh-newuser-install
```

Out of the box, with no configuration file at all, many of zsh's useful features are disabled for backward compatibility with 1990's versions. `zsh-newuser-install` suggests some recommended features to turn on.

There are many zsh configuration frameworks on the web (many of them are [on Github](https://github.com/topics/zsh-configuration)). They can be a convenient way to get started with some powerful features. The flip side of the coin is they often lock you in doing things the way the author does, so sometimes they'll prevent you from doing things the way you want. Use them at your own risk.

The zsh manual has a lot of information, but it's often written in a way that's terse and hard to follow, and has few examples. Don't hesitate to search for explanations and examples online: if you only use the part of zsh that's easy to understand in the manual, you'll miss out. Two good resources are [the zsh-users mailing list](https://www.zsh.org/cgi-bin/mla/wilma/users) and [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zsh).
An [extensive collection of articles on switching to zsh on the mac](https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh/) can be found on scriptingosx.com and [a useful Ruby script to bring your command history with you](https://gist.github.com/goyalankit/a1c88bfc69107f93cda1), can be found on Github.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if the amazing ctrl-o works on zsh. Of course, it doesn't work on Mac OS on bash either, so it's not really relevant to this answer or site. I couldn't find any information on ctrl-o in zsh in a quick online search, but then again, the information on ctrl-o in bash is also universally inaccurate...

Comment: @Jasper I didn't know bash had this. Going by the description, C-o does the same thing in zsh with the default key bindings.

Comment: I was glad to see that you included the "Some nice zsh features" section, and anxiously read it to try and understand why Apple might have made the decision to switch away from the extremely-common Bash to the much less popular Zsh. I didn't find anything at all even remotely compelling there to justify the switch. It's obviously a non-exhaustive list, but were you omitting the headline features of Zsh because they're supposed to be obvious? What am I missing here?

Comment: @CodyGray I don't know and Apple isn't in the habit of justifying themselves. It may have had something to do with the fact that if the situation had been reversed, there wouldn't be a “nice bash features” section. Or it may be because [the last non-GPLv3 bash is getting really old](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193411/update-bash-to-version-4-0-on-osx) whereas zsh has a more liberal license.

Comment: My understanding was that the licensing was essentially the only reason. It's also why bash on macOS is still v3. Word on the street is that bash won't be updated and the expectation is that it will be removed, unless the end user installs it via brew or etc. My plan was to switch to zsh sooner rather than later for macOS, but sticking to bash on Debian for the moment.

Comment: What about for non-interactive scripts that do not use Terminal (like Automator or system jobs)? (Hmm, I suppose they just use go by the `#!` and unaffected by the default login shell)

Comment: @wisbucky Scripts are not affected. Why would Automator or system jobs be an exception?

Comment: Unbiased and informative answer - much time & effort went into it. Also, great *food for thought*! After reading it, I am struck by the thought that I'll stick with `bash`, but get a current version via [`MacPorts`](https://www.macports.org/) to run alongside the ver 3.2 `bash` Apple provides. For me, *I feel `zsh` has lots of great features that I'll probably never use*... like the expensive camera I bought recently!

Comment: What is the meaning of `one[1]`? There is no `one` array defined.

Comment: @Isaac It's the first element of the array `a`. In bash, `$a` always expands to the first element of the array, even when it's followed by something that looks like an array subscript.

Comment: So, you mean to say that in **bash** `a=(one two); echo $a[1]` will print `one[1]` (That is what you wrote up there in the answer), instead, in zsh it will print just `one`. It really took me a lot of re-reading to get that meaning. Changing of shell each few words makes the statement hard to read IMhO. Could it be stated in a simpler, less convoluted way?

Comment: @Jasper Use "stty discard undef" to get ctrl-o to work on Mac.

Answer (score 26):

Change your shell now and test - no need to wait.

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

- All the scripts that depend on `bash` syntax will still find and call bash.
- the same bash from Mojave is shipping on Catalina and migrated users keep their old shell.
- Many blogs have great write-ups on moving preference files - here is one such - https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh-part-2-configuration-files/
- [Armin turned his blog series into a proper book](https://books.apple.com/book/moving-to-zsh/id1483591353?mt=11&app=itunes&at=1001lpyX) with about 22k words.

---

Also, I would estimate 95% of macOS users don't use a command line and of those that do, another 95% won't have to change anything significant or at all. *(I'd wager it's more like 10% of the 1% that know shells exist need to do anything other than port a couple lines in their .dot files)*

Your prompt will change and if you changed your prompt on `bash`, the way to change it on `zsh` is no harder and no less documented than bash.

The newer shells would fail to ever get off the ground if they broke major items or caused a painful adaptation period. If you want a more fundamental change and really want a shell you need to think about and requires training and intention to adopt - try [fish](https://fishshell.com).

Comment: I am conflicted with `fish`. I use it for two years now but the incompatibility of some copy/pasted one-lines is tiring. On the other hand it is a very handy shell (the automatic suggestions without <kbd>Tab</kbd> are excellent)

Comment: I wanted to love fish, I still want to love fish, but I have too many shell constructs from a decade in `ksh` to ever really leave that fold. I’ll gladly leave bash behind and fully embrace zsh now, personally.

Comment: I am thoroughly underwhelmed with fish. It is really just yet another Unix-like shell with a little bit less cruft. (It literally says "Finally, a command line shell for the 90s" on the homepage, after all.) The only new shell that I have seen in recent years that actually did bring something new to the (mainstream) table, was PowerShell, which unfortunately was confined to Windows much too long, and is still confined to .NET. There still is not *that* much new in PowerShell that hasn't already been done e.g. in DCL or JCL, but it has been done in a (somewhat) tasteful way.

Comment: @bmike Why not just use ksh, then?  Apple ships the most current version.  Myself, I punted bash long ago and see no reason to start using zsh now.

Comment: This answer doesn't describe the differences between bash and zsh at all though... and I'm not quite sure why specifying that "95% of macOS users don't use command line" is relevant for a question of a user which obviously does use bash.

Comment: `fish` is nothing. You really want a unique shell experience, use `tclsh`.

Comment: Before switching recklessly, one should consider moving preferences and history. Without such warning or instructions, your recommendation is incomplete and can lead to unexpected difficulties.

Comment: Instructions regarding moving configuration and history can be found here https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh-part-2-configuration-files/

Comment: @mico That's such an awesome resource. That would make a great edit to the post.

Comment: thanks @bmike. I took courage and edited the awesome main answer

Comment: @Mavrik Have a look at Armin Briegel’s stupendously amazing blog and even better book on the differences. Since proper treatment of the subject takes tens of thousands of words (IMO) I chose to focus on the ease to change and test the waters. After all, the real answer is going to be highly dependent on each individual and what they brought to bash specifically.

Comment: Great answer; it's practical and accommodating - really it is. :) But for me, there's 2 things: 1) Apple's [market cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_capitalization) is over [$1 Trillion USD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_public_corporations_by_market_capitalization#Trillion_dollar_market_capitalizations). 2) I feel ["ripped off"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripoff) when a $1T company ships 15 year-old software with a new $4K computer they sell. I love my Mac, I ain't goin' back, but... this #AntiqueSoftware is not a good thing.

Comment: @Seamus You might be shocked how small the team that works on this is. Apple tried making larger teams and it brought us worse results. Don’t look at the % revenue Mac brings in, my suspicion is we have more Mac engineers than the numbers would allow based on history.

Comment: @Seamus They made that trillion selling phones, and cutting corners, not by selling  Macs. The best people Apple has work on iOS. We are polar bears in a warming arctic, and the Mac is our ice. Very soon we'll be swimming, and soon after that we will slip under the waves, without fanfare, because people who entered the ecosystem via iOS don't realize how good the Mac used to be, and thus will not mourn the passing of it's relevance as a platform.

Comment: @chiggsy: You may be correct. I suppose time will tell. In the meantime, I've installed MacPorts & think it's excellent, and working toward macOS/Linux dual boot - nearly there  :)  The hardware is worth saving; the software - meh...

Answer (score 8):

> My shell scripts are really not that complicated

Do your shell scripts have shebang lines (begin with `#! /bin/bash` or similar)? If not, you might have unintentionally been using a bash feature, where it runs scripts without a shebang using bash. Other shells, like dash or zsh, leave it up to the OS, which would usually use `/bin/sh` instead. `/bin/sh` on macOS is, and probably will remain, a copy of `/bin/bash`, but executing bash with the name `sh` causes it to have different behaviour. 
The specifics are the Bash  manual, [6.11 Bash POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode). Some points:

> 1. Bash ensures that the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable is set.

This environment variable may affect the behaviour of a number of other tools, especially if you have GNU tools installed.

> 30. Process substitution is not available.

Process substitution is the `<(...)` or `>(...)` syntax.

> 42. The `.` and `source` builtins do not search the current directory for the filename argument if it is not found by searching PATH.

So if your script did `. foo` expecting it to source a file named `foo` in the current directory, that won't work. You should do `. ./foo`, instead.

As you can guess from the numbers, there are a lot of minor differences in behaviour of bash in POSIX mode. Best use a shebang if you mean to use bash for your scripts.

Comment: In checking it looks like the vast majority of the shell scripts I wrote or use either explicitly state /bin/bash in the shebang (very few of them) or state /bin/sh (nearly all of them), so that at least should not be an issue. Thanks.

Comment: I think process substitution is available now. I also tried it on Catalina successfully. See: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html

Comment: @Siu still won't help scripts that use `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` in the shebang. Zsh is only the default interactive shell, it didn't replace bash everywhere

Comment: @muru Ah, I understand. I did not read the answer carefully and thought that the author was talking about process substitution is not available in `zsh` 

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit of keeping things simple...

> Can anyone provide a simple practical comparison, or specific stumbling blocks I will need to know, so that I can start working towards being ready for the new shell when Catalina is released?

If you're thinking using the new default shell consider:

- If you want to give Zsh a whirl and *feel* some of the differences without changing shell settings on your machine you might try [Powerline10k in a Docker container](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#try-it-in-docker) and see if it is your cup of tea.
- If you don't need all the bells and whistles and use Bash for just basic scripts it's rather easy to set your shell as others here have explained. And if you decide you want to use [features in Bash 5](https://itsfoss.com/bash-5-release/) it's a fairly [trivial upgrade for macOS](https://scriptingosx.com/2019/02/install-bash-5-on-macos/).
- If you want to improve the portability of your scripts so they're more likely to function as expected in both shells, [test them for POSIX-compliance](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/ddg#48787) and remove any "bashisms". I've used [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) for this and it works quite well for less complicated scripts.

While no particular path is clear these three approaches should give you enough confidence to make an informed decision without over engineering the problem or solution space.