# Why so many shell in /bin

Tags: terminal, command-line, catalina

Here is the `ls` output of my `/bin` directory:

```
[csh       ksh       zsh       bash      dash      tcsh      sh      ...]
```

Prior to catalina bash was the default and now zsh is default. What's the usage of others?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317247/bash-vs-csh-vs-others-which-is-better-for-application-maintenance and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199661/what-linux-shell-should-i-use for discussions about shells and which to use. Apple switched because of [licensing issues](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=catalina+bash+zsh) with Bash.

Comment: Primary question was: "What's the usage of others?" I didn't install any of them. zsh is the default as it's still now in beta maybe that's why bash is still available. But why others?

Comment: Different people have different preferences. It's the same reason why there are Microsoft Word, Pages and LibreOffice, or different models of cars, or ...

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361870 for an overview of differences between `bash` and `zsh`. Offering more than one shell addresses legacy concerns and provides choice. There is no single answer or reason.

Comment: @nohillside So, in which OS you found both Microsoft office and libreoffice pre installed? On Fedora you'll find only bash not the other ones.

Comment: Different OS, different rules. Most unixoid systems come with a whole bunch of shells, to suite different preferences. You might as well wonder why macOS ships with nano *and* pico *and* vim *and* emacs *and* TextEdit.app. The answer is always the same :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different [shells available for Unix-like systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), and different users have different preferences. So on most Unix systems you'll find some of the most often used shells installed, to give users a choice in using whatever they prefer.

For more information about the differences between various shells see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317247/bash-vs-csh-vs-others-which-is-better-for-application-maintenance
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199661/what-linux-shell-should-i-use
- [bash vs. zsh: What are the practical differences?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361870)

The default shell is just the shell newly created user accounts get assigned as a default shell. This can easily be changed by using `chsh` or changing the entry in the Users & Groups preference pane. And it's worth nothing that the default shell of *existing* user accounts will not be changed during the upgrade to Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

Apple and Unix tools self document themselves, so you can read the manual page of each to understand their role and place.

I recommend you start with the korn shell - be different!

```
man ksh
```

I can’t speak for Apple, but the plurality of options helps software evolve and change since scripts based on previous tools can keep working when a change happens to the default or not hold back newcomers from solving a problem in a different way than an existing shell.