# After switch to zsh history not saved

Tags: macos, terminal, mojave, zsh

I am running Mojave have changed default shell from bash to zsh.  I notice history is not saved between sessions.

Following recommendations in [What are the practical differences between Bash and Zsh?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361957/115093) I ran :

```
autoload -U zsh-newuser-install
zsh-newuser-install
```

This created the files `~/.zshrc` and `~/.histfile` which I did not have before but the history seems not to be updated.

```
A1398% cat .zshrc 
# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
setopt beep
bindkey -e
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
# The following lines were added by compinstall
zstyle :compinstall filename '/Users/hali/.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# End of lines added by compinstall
A1398% cat .histfile 
A1398%
```

On opening a new session (either Terminal or iTerm2) there is nothing previous and up arrow for previous commands does nothing.

Do I understand correctly and history *should* be in `~/.histfile`? Are there any other required steps?

Comment: Can't replicate it in my VM (Catalina though) after dumping my .zprofile and relaunching Terminal...it (your .zshrc) just works

Comment: Do you type `exit` to terminate a shell session?

Comment: Why not continue running bash?  The only one who thinks you need to change your shell is you.

Comment: @fd0 - it appears `exit` was the answer.  There appears to be some delay writing to *.histfile* and `exit` flushes previous commands to the file.  I was conflating the results of my missing *.zshrc* (which results in no history) with *.histfile* apparently not being updated.

Comment: @MarcWilson - just tried it for fun/curiosity really.  I noticed zsh was a changed default in Catalina so thought I'd try it.  I don't see much difference from bash that affects me though tbh.

Comment: @Ix07 Since you solved your problem, how about closing your question?