# How to change zsh prompt which now shows probably MAC address?

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh

I have been try to change the prompt on my terminal and the prompt that shows up looks like a MAC address.

This is what it looks like:

```
Last login: Mon Dec 16 20:41:33 on ttys000
thomasleonscribnerjr@android-fc473fc19d7d6b57
```

I am using a MacBook Pro.  I have never tethered my laptop through a phone. I use ZSH shell. I just wanted to use the $ symbol

Comment: Is your MacBook Pro tethering through your Android phone?

Comment: If you edit this to ask specifically what you want to have for your prompt we can point you to a modification. Bonus points if you edit which shell you use so we don’t have to guess.

Comment: Also, you’re not hacked. It’s that your network DNS is unmanaged.

Comment: This is no hack but the silent revenge of your MBP for killing Apples like [this](https://youtu.be/TU8a5XV5-Ss?t=488).

Comment: No I have never tethered my laptop through a phone.  I use ZSH shell.  I just wanted to use the $ symbol.

Comment: @FunwithPedrosFamilyFriends https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361957/313842 has a section of Prompt. give it a read! and use @ to notify people, one person per comment.

Comment: How did you change your prompt and what file contains your changes?