# I get errors when trying to install GTK+3 on my Mac OSX 10.9 system

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path

I'm trying to install GTK+3 on my Mac OSX 10.9 system to run a pyGObject project I've been developing in Ubuntu. It runs perfectly on Ubuntu, so I wanted to test cross-platform compatibility. I'm following the directions on [wiki.gnome.org](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show//Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building?action=show&redirect=GTK%2B%2FOSX%2FBuilding).

I finished the part where I run the `sh gtk-osx-build-setup.sh` command. It loads everything perfectly (as far as I can tell). However, if I do a `which jhbuild` or try a command, I get an error:

```
EnvironmentError: MacOSX10.9.sdk not found
jhbuild: could not load config file
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this and finish installing `jhbuild`? It seems like the instructions from their webpage are a little incomplete or perhaps I'm not adding to path correctly?

Questions:

1. Which file do I put the path? Is it `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` (neither have worked so far). Perhaps some other file is my bash profile script?
2. What is the path to the jhbuild? In the example, it says `alias jhbuild="PATH=gtk-prefix/bin:$PATH jhbuild"`, but I'm not actually sure what I should substitute in for `gtk-prefix` (not sure where the actual path is, since `which jhbuild` doesn't work).

Comment: It is ~/.bash_profile to edit the PATH for use in terminal see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119714/237 - we need to see what is in this file. The easiest way to install complex C programs is to use a package manager e.g. Macports, Homebrew

Comment: I would second Mark's suggestion though. Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) is a LOT less painful.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a CentOS 6.4 install and even though it's in the PATH in the .bashrc, it doesn't allow me to `import gi` in Python. A real pain, so far. It is resulting in lost time, so I'm using PyGtk with GTK+2 and it's working fine so far as a temporary solution.

Comment: And I agree, Homebrew is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if this is a silly question but do you have Xcode installed?

The OSX SDK should be installed on your system within the Xcode application bundle. You should be able to find it at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/`.

If Xcode isn't installed you can install it for free from [here](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).

Comment: Xcode says it's installed and up to date.