# Why don't changes in the bashrc file work on a new terminal window?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, alias

I'm trying to add an alias to the bashrc file. Since I'm not good at this, Im' going to write all the steps I took

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

The file had this in it

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

On top of that I added my alias

```
dropUpload(){
~/drop.sh upload $1 $2
}
alias dropU=dropUpload
```

Saved the file and then sourced it with `. ~/.bashrc`

In the same window I tried using the code `dropU first/url second/url` and it worked. I closed the terminal window and opened a new one, the code no longer works. The error I get is

> -bash: dropU: command not found

If I `nano` back to the file my new code is there. If I re-source the file, the code works. How can I get this to persist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in my `~/.bash_profile` have this code

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

@Mark have a greate answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119714/174655).

I found a link that clear that case at [Unix FAQ for OSX](http://hayne.net/MacDev/Notes/unixFAQ.html#shellStartup).

It wrote

> **Bash Startup Files**
>
> When a "login shell" starts up, it reads the file "/etc/profile" and then "~/.bash_profile" or "~/.bash_login" or "~/.profile" (whichever one exists - it only reads one of these, checking for them in the order mentioned).
>
> When a "non-login shell" starts up, it reads the file "/etc/bashrc" and then the file "~/.bashrc".
>
> Note that when bash is invoked with the name "sh", it tries to mimic the startup sequence of the Bourne shell ("sh"). In particular, a non-login shell invoked as "sh" does not read any dot files by default. See the bash man page for details.

Comment: could someone tell me why my answer got a downvote?

Comment: That didn't work for me. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: First, we confirm that your `.bashrc` sourced automatically on your new terminal session. You can try to add to `.bashrc` a simple alias like `alias myEcho='echo Anubeloredelana'`, which print `Anubeloredelana` onto the terminal, and in a new terminal session try to call it to see if it work.

Comment: The answer given by @Mark [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119711/why-mac-os-x-dont-source-bashrc/119714#119714) is 100% correct -- Terminal sources `~/.bash_profile`, not `~/.bashrc`. Double check that you added the correct lines to your `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: FIXED! after you told me to add `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc fi` I realised I was adding it in both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. Now it works. I can't upvote (not enough reputation) but thanks for your help @binhsonnguyen

Comment: they are not only commands, they are the way that the os work for you. cheers.