# Terminal and iTerm appear to be partially opening in zsh

Tags: macos, high-sierra, bash, iterm, zsh

I recently installed Julia on my iMac running High Sierra. Julia seems to want to run in the Z-shell whereas I normally use bash. I haven't run Julia today but my Term2 windows are screwed up since installing Jullia. It used to be that when I was using iTerm, the command line listed the name of my current directory followed by the cursor. Now when I use it the command line contains a long character string.  If I run bash, the command line returns to normal. Any hints on how to get iTerm from starting in the Z-shell. An image of the terminal has too small print to read... The cursor line used to look like so:

`my_user_name/computer_name:/Volumes/MyBook/Applications$`

but now it looks like:

```
\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]$
```

Comment: Julia runs in any shell. ITerm Profiles->Open Profiles shoes the setup. If you edit the profile it shows which shell you are using and the start parameters

Comment: I tried that but there is no mention of the z-shell.

Comment: How are you starting bash rather than zsh in iTerm

Comment: Yes iTerm sources a .bash_profile file and i've set options somewhere to start in bash shell. Its been working fine for years until I installed Julia.

Comment: i just fixed this in the preferences for iTerm and Terminal. I changed from login shell  to command. In the command box I put /bin/bash. This fixed the problem. I'd still like to know why I have to do that...

Comment: It that case see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119714/237  Also did you use .profile as your startup file? The particular Julia install might have edited the correct file .bash_profile

Comment: i downloaded a week old .bash_profile from a recent Time Macine backup. No difference.

Comment: WHat does `echo $TERM` show in both cases

Comment: xterm-256color in all cases...