# Adding a new directory to PATH varibale

Tags: path, binary

What is the de-facto way to export a binary/executable to my global PATH? I have seen different answers to this, but I am looking for the best answer.

Basically, if I go on Github and download a directory or folder and then I want to add whatever I download to my PATH, what is the recommended way to do that, so that I can echo it in any shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the directory in `PATH` variable in `~/.bashrc` file. When an interactive, non-login shell is started, `~/.bashrc` is executed. That means `~/.bashrc` is executed for every new tab/window opened in Terminal.app.

Simply add this line in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/DirectoryName
PATH=~/DirectoryName:$PATH
```

as per your preference. If the directory name is prepended, any system executable of similar name may get shadowed.

To execute `~/.bashrc` and get the new `PATH` in effect without restarting terminal, execute:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Also, make sure to enter this line in your `~/.bash_profile`

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ] ; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: could i add it to .bash_profile instead of .bashrc?

Comment: @CodyRutscher As you mentioned, you are looking for the best approach. I'd recommend adding it to `~/.bashrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile`. `~/.bash_profile` is executed for login shells, while `~/.bashrc` is executed for interactive non-login shells. That means `~/.bashrc` is executed every time you open a new tab/window in Terminal.app.

Comment: @NimeshNeema ~/.bash_profile is used every time you open a new tab in Terminal. Each new instance is via login and so ~/.bashrc is not sourced https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119711/why-doesnt-mac-os-x-source-bashrc/119714#119714

Comment: @Mark Thanks for pointing out. I totally missed that. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @NimeshNeema This is almost certainly a suplicate better to find this and close the question as a dup.

Comment: If `.bashrc` is "executed", I think you mean sourced, in every Terminal.app window or tab then why would you need to source it in `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to one line it (which I find more convenient):

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:"/path/to/your/dir"' >> ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile
```

of course you can change this to your preferences (ie. append or prepend to $PATH, .bashrc, .bash_profile, .zshrc, etc.)

Comment: You just overwrote anyother setting that had previously been declared in .bash_profile

Comment: @fd0 oh you're right. I'll fix that